# Haskell type errors?

Tags: haskell

I'm really new to Haskell, and it's giving me quite a time. I was trying to write a basic function similar to 'linspace' in Matlab but the compiler seems to reject the idea that 'floor' produces an Integral type. My code:

```
linspace :: Double -> Double -> Double -> [Double]
linspace x dx y
    | y' == y   = [x + i * dx | i <- nums]
    | otherwise = ([x + i * dx | i <- nums] ++ [y])
    where
        n = floor ((y - x) / dx)
        nums = [0..n]
        y' = (x + (fromIntegral n) * dx)
```

Which produces an error in ghci:

```
maths.hs:8:21: error:
    * No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of `floor'
    * In the expression: floor ((y - x) / dx)
      In an equation for `n': n = floor ((y - x) / dx)
      In an equation for `linspace':
          linspace x dx y
            | y' == y = [x + i * dx | i <- nums]
            | otherwise = ([x + i * dx | i <- nums] ++ [y])
            where
                n = floor ((y - x) / dx)
                nums = [0 .. n]
                y' = (x + (fromIntegral n) * dx)

maths.hs:10:28: error:
    * No instance for (Integral Double)
        arising from a use of `fromIntegral'
    * In the first argument of `(*)', namely `(fromIntegral n)'
      In the second argument of `(+)', namely `(fromIntegral n) * dx'
      In the expression: (x + (fromIntegral n) * dx)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: You may want to look at the type of `floor`. It may surprise you. You'll need to replace `floor ((y - x) / dx) ` with `fromInteger (floor ((y - x) / dx))`.

Comment: @Alec Don't you mean `toInteger`?

Comment: @AmiTavory Yes, Oops. :)

Comment: @Alec Not a big deal; it was an obvious typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version compiles:

```
linspace :: Double -> Double -> Double -> [Double]                                                                                                                   
linspace x dx y
    | y' == y   = [x + (fromIntegral i) * dx | i <- nums]
    | otherwise = ([x + (fromIntegral i) * dx | i <- nums] ++ [y])
    where
        n = toInteger $ floor ((y - x) / dx)
        nums = [0..n]
        y' = (x + (fromIntegral n) * dx)
```

What are the changes?

- As @Alec commented, while `floor` is *logically* an integer, it's type is not. You need to use `toInteger`.
- Following that, you need to use `fromIntegral` when multiplying `i` and `dex.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please elaborate on the type of `floor`? I spent a good amount of time staring at:
    `Prelude> :t floor
    floor :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b`
yesterday so I'm still pretty confused.

Comment: Are you familiar with `typeclass`es? It is a `typeclass` which `Integer` and `Int` instantiate (see [here](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/Integral_c.html)).

Answer (score 5):

You have bound the result of `linspace` to be a `[Double]`, due to the type annotation. Therefore, `[x + i * dx | i <- nums]` must produce such a list of `Double`s. `x` and `dx` are bound to be `Double` as they are parameters passed to the function, which are all declared as `Double`. But what about `i`? It stems from `nums`; to have `i` be a `Double`, `nums` must be a `[Double]`.

Nums is defined as

```
nums = [0..n]
```

Okay, `nums` is a list alright. But a list of *what*? That depends on `n`; let's take a look!

```
n = floor ((y - x) / dx)
```

`floor` takes, in a nutshell, your `Double` and produces an `Integral`. Therefore, `nums` is a list of integrals. This is the error you're getting: there is no instance of `Integral` for `Double`; there is no way for the types to work out nicely.

To fix those errors, you have to make `n` a `Double`:

```
n = fromIntegral $ floor ((y - x) / dx)
```

As such, your definition of `y'` must be changed as well:

```
y' = x + n * dx
```

## In a nutshell

```
linspace :: Double -> Double -> Double -> [Double]
linspace x dx y
    | y' == y   = [x + i * dx | i <- nums]
    | otherwise = ([x + i * dx | i <- nums] ++ [y])
    where
        n = fromIntegral $ floor ((y - x) / dx)
        nums = [0.. n]
        y' = (x + n * dx)
```